# How to prevent complete resizing of linear gradient overlay on smaller screen sizes

Tags: css, responsive-design, linear-gradients

I created a very simple parallax effect on a banner img by setting its `background-attachment: fixed`. I've added a linear gradient overlay using the `pseudo element after`.

It works like a dime. When I scroll down the content and gradient flow over the banner image upwards.

However, when I decrease my screen size the linear gradient responds by being pushed to the left and upwards and getting smaller in the process. All of the lines are crammed top left and no stripes are going from the top to the bottom of the image, as shown in the code snippet after resizing.

I actually want it to look something like shown in the image. Here the yellow band on the outside right keeps flowing from top to bottom on smaller screen sizes.

Is there a way to have the overlay to cover the image from top to bottom on smaller screen sizes? So that at least one of the coloured stripes (the one on the right flows under an angle from to top to the bottom of the image?

[image: linear gradient on top of banner image]

```css
.jumbotron-header {
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/1400x500?mountains');
  background-color: green;
  /* Used if the image is unavailable */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: relative;
  height: 75vh;
}

.jumbotron-header::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(107deg,
      blue,
      blue 5%,
      yellow 5%,
      yellow 10%,
      green 10%,
      green 15%,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
<div class="jumbotron-header mb-5"></div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-1" role="main">


      <h1>Some Title</h1>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis unde
        aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>
        
        <hr>
        
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis unde
        aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>
        
        <hr>
        
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis unde
        aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the `calc()` function.

`height: calc(100vh - 40vh)` for the background.

And

```
width: calc(100vh + 40vh);

height: calc(100vh - 40vh);
```

for the linear gradient

```css
.jumbotron-header {
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/1400x500?mountains');
  background-color: green;
  /* Used if the image is unavailable */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100vh - 40vh);
}

.jumbotron-header::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100vh + 40vh);
  height: calc(100vh - 40vh);
  top: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(107deg,
      blue,
      blue 5%,
      yellow 5%,
      yellow 10%,
      green 10%,
      green 15%,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
<div class="jumbotron-header mb-5"></div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-1" role="main">


      <h1>Some Title</h1>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis unde
        aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>
        
        <hr>
        
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis unde
        aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>
        
        <hr>
        
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis unde
        aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

```css
.jumbotron-header {
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/1400x500?mountains');
  background-color: green;
  /* Used if the image is unavailable */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: relative;
  height: 75vh;
}

.jumbotron-header::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(107deg,
      blue,
      blue 5%,
      yellow 5%,
      yellow 10%,
      green 10%,
      green 15%,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
<div class="jumbotron-header mb-5"></div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-1" role="main">


      <h1>Some Title</h1>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis unde
        aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>
        
        <hr>
        
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis unde
        aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>
        
        <hr>
        
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis unde
        aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```